# Trying to update Values in Standard Object from metaData

Tags: apex, trigger, community, custom-metadata, after-trigger

Trigger is updated to `Before UPdate`I am using Trigger isBefore In `System.debug(opp.get(metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c)` it is showing correct Values but not Updating in Opportunity Object

Below is Trigger and its Apex Class
Trigger

```
trigger MetadataObjectFieldMapping on Opportunity (before insert, before update) 
{
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate )
    {
        MetadataObjectFieldMappingHandler oppHandler = new MetadataObjectFieldMappingHandler();
        oppHandler.Show(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

and Apex Class

```
public class MetadataObjectFieldMappingHandler {
    List<String> strAccField = new List<String>();
    //Getting List of MetaData Values
    List<Object_Field_Mapping__mdt> metaData = new List<Object_Field_Mapping__mdt>
                                                        ([SELECT Account_Field_Name__c,
                                                             Opportunity_Field_Name__c 
                                                                 FROM Object_Field_Mapping__mdt]);
    //Function to check if Field Name Exists in Object or not
    public Boolean hello(String objName, String fieldName)
    {
        Boolean temp = False;
        //Creating Schema to get all fields from Account and Opportunity Object
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> accFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();     
        for(Schema.SObjectField field : accFields.values())
        {
                    strAccField.add(field+'');
        }
        //Calling Account and Opportunity Object in fieldName
        if(strAccField.contains(fieldName)){
            System.debug('PASS '+fieldName);
            temp = true;
        }
        return temp;
    }
    public void Show(List<opportunity> newOppList)
    {       
        Boolean test1 = hello('Account',metaData.get(0).Account_Field_Name__c);
        Boolean test2 = hello('Opportunity',metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c);
        //If both Field Value exists
        if(test1 && test2){
            //Getting value from Opp using dynamic Query
            String query = 'Select Account.'+metaData.get(0).Account_Field_Name__c+', '+metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c+' from Opportunity where Id IN : newOppList ';
            List<Opportunity> oppList =database.query(query);
            for(Opportunity opp : oppList){
                opp.put(
                    metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c, 
                    opp.Account.get(metaData.get(0).Account_Field_Name__c)
                );
                System.debug(opp.get(metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c));
            }
        }
}
```

@David - Can you please tell me, why Value is not Updating..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
opp.get(metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c) = opp.Account.get(metaData.get(0).Account_Field_Name__c);
```

The result of `opp.get()` is not an *lvalue*; it does not represent a location to which you can assign a value on the left-hand side of an assignment statement. Put another way, it returns a value, but not a reference to the value's location.

The inverse of `get()` is [`put()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#!), and I think that's what you meant to do here:

```
opp.put(
    metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c, 
    opp.Account.get(metaData.get(0).Account_Field_Name__c)
);
```

Rolling up from comments:

- You also appear to have suffered from trigger recursion while working in `after update` context, possibly stemming from a misdesign of where the trigger runs. Each time an Opportunity is updated, you update it again, firing another trigger invocation.

  If this trigger really belongs on Opportunity (as opposed to on Account), you should consider the two [possibilities for avoiding trigger recursion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270124/i-have-one-trigger-for-tas-project-object-and-another-trigger-for-proj-object-t/270142#270142) that I describe in another recent answer:

  - Checking before doing work.
  - Using a static Boolean only to stop the recursive call.

  Here, it looks like your trigger really just needs to check whether it has any updates to make before firing the update DML.
- You've also run afoul of the fact that magic `before update` behavior is only available if you modify the sObject instances in `Trigger.new`. You're re-querying them here, which results in your changes being lost. To persist those changes in `before update` context, you have to use Maps to correlate your queried objects back to `Trigger.new` via Id, and make your updates exclusively through `Trigger.new`.

Answer (score -3):

```
if(test1 && test2){
            //Getting value from Opp using dynamic Query
            for(Opportunity opp : newOppList){
                opp.put(
                    metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c, 
                    opp.Account.get(metaData.get(0).Account_Field_Name__c)
                );
                System.debug(opp.get(metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c));
            }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Right now, this is what we'd call a _code dump_. Code dumps tend not to be great answers because they don't go over _why_ the proposed code should work, _how_ it works, or _how_ it addresses the issue. Code dumps don't usually help the person asking the question understand the issue (so they can avoid similar problems in the future), and tend to generate a lot of "that didn't work" and "try this instead" in the comments, which makes it hard for other people with similar issues to apply to their own situations.